# Azure Internal to External IP addresses - do they exit the datacenter network?

Tags: azure

I have a three Azure VMs, two of them have a load balanced endpoint.  The third needs to communicate to this load balanced endpoint via the lb's public IP address.  In Azure, will this traffic exit the datacenter?  My assumption is that it would get to the edge of the datacenter network but would travel no further and is "relatively" secure.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any documentation that would confirm this.

Is my assumption correct and can anyone provide validating documentation?

Comment: I would also assume it would just go to the edge router. The other equation that you should ask yourself is "will this traffic be considered as outside datacenter or inside". Because if is considered outside DC you will have to pay for what goes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traffic within a region will not leave the datacenter and will not incur charges.  There is a research paper at http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/80693/vl2-sigcomm09-final.pdf that formed the basis of the new Q10 Azure network architecture.  It doesn't specifically talk about Azure endpoints, but you can see that the architecture allows for efficient routing of traffic purely within the datacenter.

You can also watch http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/AZR302 where Mark discusses the new Q10 architecture starting at 27:30.  Where he discusses storage clusters you can think of it in the same way as the public IP for your service since they both work the same way at the network layer.

You can also see http://davidpallmann.blogspot.com/2010/08/hidden-costs-in-cloud-part-2-windows.html, which is not official documentation, but does describe the traffic and costs.

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I am looking for.  A related question I have is whether a site-to-site VPN can route traffic INLCUDING internet through the VPN tunnel.  For example, if I setup the site-to-site, should it then be able to pass internet traffic through the private network to the public IP address.

Answer (score -1):

Accessing a VM using its external IP address from a VM inside the data center will effectively exit the datacenter and this will result in outbound traffic charges and some latency.