# Routing between two Azure VMs in same region when using external IP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've got two Azure Virtual Machines which both reside in the US-East-2 region. For billing reasons I cannot put them into a virtual network (each VM is on a different subscription) but I can connect from VM1 to VM2 using VM1's Public IP.

Will Azure route the traffic internally or will I get billed for regular internet traffic?

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is here on the [Data Transfer Pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/):

> **Is data transfer between Azure services located within the same region charged?**
>   No. For example, an Azure SQL database in the same region
>   will not have any additional data transfer costs.

Note that Azure subscriptions are containers for access control and organization.  I don't think there is a fundamental difference between connecting services within a single subscription vs. between services in separate subscriptions.

Comment: Well I've tried it using the portal and it seems to be impossible to have resources created by one subscription join a VNet created by another subscription.

Comment: That does not specifically say that it applies when using external IPs. Which is ok if they don't care. But google for example has roughly the same text but they would charge "Traffic sent between the external IP address of two virtual machines in the same region will be charged as Egress between zones in the same region, even if the virtual machines are in the same zone."

Comment: @zapl: I couldn't find it explicitly stating anywhere, but I verified in our own subscription that both an external request and a request between services in the subscription resolves to the same external IP address.  So I would extrapolate from that internal requests between external IP's are considered inter-regional traffic.  But I would love to find an authoritative source confirming that.

Comment: Was just curious because I've recently read above exception. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912163/azure-internal-to-external-ip-addresses-do-they-exit-the-datacenter-network agrees with you.